# STM32F746 on Nucleo-F746ZG - difference between PWM1 and PWM2 signal names

Tags: nucleo

I understand that each timer channel can be configured at either mode 1 or mode 2.
On the timer  signal names, I see "PWM1" or "PWM2."
I'm confused by this nomenclature.
Does it mean that this signal is already configured as one mode or the other?  If so, how is that impacted by the OCxM bits in the TIMx_CCMRx register?

Comment: Those are probably distinct channels

Comment: More likely means you have 2 different PWM generators. Either can (probably: but see data-sheet and user guides) be configured in either mode.